# Declared InjectionToken cannot be found on compile of Angular application

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Im trying to provide a global configuration, which is dependent on the user's webbrowser, by using an `InjectionToken`.  However the declared const cannot be found in the source code on compiling the application.  I have seen this pattern work before(1), but I am not sure what I am doing differently.  Below is an abstract of my code.

```js
// ./services/system/masks.service

export declare const NUMBER_MASK: InjectionToken<string>;

export function NumberMaskFactory(): NumberMask {
    const lang = navigator.language.substring(0, 2);
    if (lang == "en") {
        const radix: string = getLocaleNumberSymbol(navigator.language, NumberSymbol.Decimal);
        const thousandSeperator: string = getLocaleNumberSymbol(navigator.language, NumberSymbol.Group);

        return new NumberMask(radix, thousandSeperator);
    }
    return new NumberMask(".", ",");
}


export class NumberMask {
    public radix: string;
    public thousandSeparator: string;
    constructor(radix: string, thousandSeparator: string) {
        this.radix = radix;
        this.thousandSeparator = thousandSeparator;
    }
}
```

```js
// app.module.ts
import { NumberMaskFactory, NUMBER_MASK } from "./services/system/masks.service";
// ...
providers: [
        {
            provide: NUMBER_MASK,
            useFactory: NumberMaskFactory

        }
// ...
```

On compile this throws me the following error:

> ./src/app/app.module.ts:112:21-32 - Error: export 'NUMBER_MASK' (imported as 'NUMBER_MASK') was not found in './services/system/masks.service' (possible exports: NumberMask, NumberMaskFactory)

(Note 1) For example for `MSAL_INSTANCE` in this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create injection token you have to instantiate

```
 export const NUMBER_MASK = new InjectionToken<string>('');
```

Comment: Thanks! I had wrongly assumed the dependency injection would do this for me.